# Does $f(X)$ with $X=[x_1, x_2]$ mean $X$ appear as a whole in the definition of $f$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a mapping with $f(X)$ and $X=[x_1, x_2] \in \mathbb R^2$.

So does $f(X) = g(x_1, x_2)$ make sense for any mapping $g$ with the same range as $f$?

Must $X$ be able to appear as a whole in the representation of $f(X)$? For example, in $f(X) = x_1 + x_2 = X^T [1,1]^T$, $X$ can be represented as a whole. Another example, in $f(X) = x_1 \times x_2$, $X$ seems not be able to be represented as a whole.

If $f(X)$ doesn't require $X$ to be able appear as a whole, how can we wrote  a notation that requires $X$ to appear as a whole in $f(X)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "represented as a whole?"

Comment: It means $f(X)$ can be represented in terms an expression of $X$, not just of the components $x_i$'s of $X$.

Comment: You can always read off an element of $X$ from an expression with $X$ "represented as a whole". E.g. $x_1=X\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$ (or strictly speaking, $x_1=\operatorname{trace}(X\pmatrix{1\\ 0})$).

Comment: @user1551:Thanks! What if $X$ is in $S^d$ for an arbitrary set $S$ not necessarily $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean. Perhaps you could edit the question to reflect the actual context of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Does $f(X) = g(x_1,x_2)$ make sense for any mapping $g$ with the same range as $f$?

Yes, it does. Read on for an explanation why.

> Must $X$ be able to appear as a whole in the representation of $f(X)$?

Again, yes, it does. Fortunately, this is always possible. Namely, the defining property of $X = [x_1, x_2]$, that justifies calling it a "tuple" to begin with, is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ together uniquely determine $X$, and vice versa, that $X$ uniquely fixes $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Let us immediately pass to the general case of an $n$-tuple $X \in S^d$ for some set $S$.

Usually, when we want to use the coordinates of $X$, we introduce the so-called *projection functions* (often simply called *projections*):

$$p_i: S^d \to S: p_i (X) = x_i$$

where $x_i$ is in the $i$th position of the tuple $X$.

Using these $p_i$, we can e.g. rewrite $g(x_1, x_2)$ as:

$$g(x_1, x_2) = g(p_1 (X), p_2 (X))$$

in which $X$ only occurs "as a whole".

Now, once we have been comforted ourselves with the use of the $p_i$, it is very convenient to start writing $x_i$ instead of $p_i (X)$ when we define functions on tuples. In the end, this is just a small abuse of notation that greatly simplifies formulas, but does not compromise the full rigour in terms of the $p_i$ lying underneath.